# Sometimes normal conversion fails on Windows with error 1

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I run `ffmpeg.exe` from node (`spawn()`) and sometimes (not random but depending on the day) it fails on Windows with error `1`

I use a very basic syntax:

```
const outputPath = getTempFolder() + path.sep + 'video.mp4';
const command = spawn(ffmpegPath, [
  '-i',
  getTempFolder() + path.sep + 'video.webm',
  '-y',
  outputPath
]);
```

Any idea why this could happen and eventually how to debug it? Thanks!

Comment: Is it a problem with `ffmpeg.exe` or with your code or both? Show the log from the ffmpeg process from one of the failures (assuming ffmpeg even executes).

Comment: @llogan any idea how to get such log?

Comment: ffmpeg outputs to stderr so you can redirect the output to a file, or add the `-report` option and it will create an overly verbose log file in the working directory.